# 2 Component Spinor Formalism

Tags: quantum-field-theory, spinors

In Chapters 34-36 of the Srednicki QFT book, 2-component spinors and their combinations in Dirac and Majorana spinors are carefully constructed. Specifically, in equations 36.14 and 36.15 the following left-handed spinors are defined:

$$
\begin{equation}
 \begin{split}
  &\chi = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\psi_1 + i\psi_2)\\
  &\xi = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\psi_1 - i\psi_2)
 \end{split} 
\end{equation}
$$

A couple of pages later, charge conjugation is then defined as "Charge conjugation simply exchanges $\chi$ and $\xi$".

Now, I have read in other books (e.g. Georgi) that if a particle is defined in one SU(2) representation of the Lorentz group (e.g. as left handed spinor), then the corresponding anti-particle is in the other representation (e.g. as right handed spinor).However, in the above definition in Srednicki, both fermion and anti-fermion are left-handed spinors.

Have I got this right? How can both of these statements be correct? Any help to clear up my confusion would be greatly appreciated.

As an aside, I have a more general issue understanding the intuition behind Dirac spinors. The state of a general fermion or anti-fermion is often given with a Dirac spinor $\Psi$. If this fermion has mass, then the fermion is a combination of a left-handed and right handed spinor, as in Srednicki:
$$
\Psi = \begin{pmatrix} \chi_c \\ \xi^{\dagger\dot{c}} \end{pmatrix}.
$$

As helicity and handedness are frame dependent, I can kind of understand how the Dirac fermion can be a combination of the two above. However, Dirac fermions can also by viewed as a combination of a fermion and anti-fermion in much the same way. I do not fully understand this. How can a fermion with mass be described by a field that is partly particle and partly anti-particle?

Again, any insights that the community could provide would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm working on turning this into an answer, but I think [this](http://www.quantumdiaries.org/2011/06/19/helicity-chirality-mass-and-the-higgs/) will be a useful read. (If someone else wants to post an answer before I get to it, go right ahead.)

Comment: Somebody asked me the same question (in private) a month or so ago; she returned to me with this pdf which helped her immensely; I wonder if it helps you too, c.f., pages 199-201  http://www.physics.indiana.edu/~dermisek/QFT_09/qft-I-9-4p.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Fermion is left-handed spinor and anti-fermion is right-handed spinor.

Firstly, you can see that $\xi = \chi ^{\dagger}$. From Sredniski, "... that hermitian conjugation swaps the two SU(2) Lie algebras...the hermitian conjugate of a field in the (2,1) representation should be a field in the (1,2) representation"... Thus $\chi$ is a right-handed fermion while $\xi$ the opposite.

Maybe you should read Chap.34, especially between eqn. (34.10) to (34.13)...